# Hover over image making it transparent and showing text

Tags: html, css, image, hover, transparency

Hey I'm working on a portfolio page (just using HTML and CSS) and I created a grid of images. My plan is that the one image that is hovered over gets transparent (0.2 transparency or so) and a description text appears at this field.

I created following code, but this makes my description text transparent as well.
How can I get the text to stay fully visible?

HTML:

```
<div id="imagelist">
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/img1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Image 1" />
        <p class="imgtext">This is the description text.
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Can you help me with the CSS part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked on it

Made some changes try it out

```
<style>
            #imagelist a {position: relative;display: inline-block;}
            #imagelist a p{display: none;}
            #imagelist a:hover p{position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;background: #000;opacity: 0.8;top: 0;left: 0;margin: 0;display: block;}
            #imagelist a p span{display: inline-table;width: 100%;height: 100%;text-align: center;color:#fff;}
            #imagelist a p span span{display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}
        </style>


<div id="imagelist">
            <a href="">
                <img src="img/img1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Image 1" />
                <p class="imgtext">
                <span>
                    <span>This is the description text.</span>
                </span>
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

It looks quite simple just added some few extra tags with it. Try it out and let me know the feedback

Comment: Hey thanks alot, this actually worked after some fine adjustments!

Answer (score 0):

When the div is in a hover state target the Image element to change opacity and change the display property for the description.

```css
#imagelist:hover img {
  opacity: .2;  
}

#imagelist:hover .imgtext {
  display: block;
}

.imgtext {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="imagelist">
   <a href="">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg"                                           
                 width="200px" 
                 height="200px" 
                 alt="Image 1"/>
    <p class="imgtext">This is the description text.
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the text should appear behind the transparent picture? Also, are all thumbnails 200px by 200px?

If yes, you could do it like this:

```css
#imagelist a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#imagelist img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#imagelist img:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagelist">
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://s0.geograph.org.uk/geophotos/03/97/06/3970600_94c29e78.jpg" />
    <p class="imgtext">This is the description text.
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```